# How do I parse this xml?

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I need to parse the following xml code in c# using system.xml. I need a list of strings containing the content of the tags User.

```
<Configuration>
   ....
   <DebugUsersMail>
     <User>bob@example.com</User>
     <User>lenny@example.com</User>
   </DebugUsersMail>
   ...
</Configuration>
```

Comment: You have missed the sample xml

Comment: You should check out the [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx), and [XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx) classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
List<string> returnList = new List<string>();
XmlNodeList node = xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("DebugUsersMail");
XmlNodeList childNodes = node[0].ChildNodes;
for(int i = 0; i < childNodes.Count; i++)
{
   returnList.Add(childNodes[i].InnerText);
}
return returnList;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can use Linq something like this is nice and simple

```
    XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("C:\\your_xml_file.xml");
    List<string> users = xmlDoc.Descendants("User").Select(xElem => (string)xElem).ToList();
```

You'll need to include a reference to System.Xml.Linq in your using statements to use the XDocument object.

This does however assume that there are no other User elements in the xml file that you don't want included in the list.

If you want to be more specific you could do this

```
List<string> users = xmlDoc.Descendants("DebugUsersMail")
                           .Descendants("User").Select(xElem => (string)xElem).ToList();
```

Comment: I get the following error message when I trie to compile this code: System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) I did reference the assembly. I use .Net Framework 3.5. Do I need version 4.0 for this code?

Comment: It looks like your not referencing Linq in your using statements. Try adding using System.Linq; to your usings. It should work fine on 3.5 as thats what I compliled it for

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of ways to do it in C#. You can use:

- XmlDocument andthen XPath and XQuery
- XDocument and Linq
- XmlTextReader/SAX
- Regular expressions
- Deserialise the XML to objects

The route to take depends a lot of what the rest of XML looks like.

Comment: System.xml contains all above.

Comment: @Luke: what have you tried? Have you read the MSDN docs on system.xml?